# Accessing module tag

Tags: templates, tags, playframework

I'd like to extend an existing module by adding a tag in the views/tags folder. Then I would like to be able to call this tag from one of my application template which is using this module. Exactly like it's done in the Secure module with the check.tag.

However when I try to call my module tag from one of my application template, Play only search through my application "tags" folder and doesn't check for the module tags folder.

So, is there a way to tell Play to import the tags located in the module?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure you provide the namespace of the tag.  For example, in the secure module, the tags are under

`secure/app/views/tags`

so everything under tags counts as the namespace.

The path to check is

`secure/check.tag`

so the usage in the templates is

`#{secure.check}`

Comment: Indeed, it was a problem in the namespace I was using and the folder structure I used. Thank you